# node reference and taxonomy

Tags: reference, drupal-taxonomy

I want to combine node reference and taxonomy.
I have added a vocabulary with some options, those options will display in the dropdown on any content page of specific content type. Say in in all pages of STORY content type it will display.
I have created new content type sat LAYOUT, and all pages of LAYOUT content type displaying in all pages of STORY content type with help of CCK(node referrence).

But i want the options in such a way that in the in all the pages of STORY content type i have to display all pages of LAYOUT content type in dropdown, along with taxanomy dropdown. i.e if i created 10 pages of LAYOUT content type, then 10 taxanomy dropdowns have to be created dynamically.
I mean, for a page of STORY type i want to know which taxonomy has been selected for a selected node reference of type LAYOUT content type pages.

Please help me how to do this.